# How to show the full graph in a jupyter cell and export the full image instead of the part of the embedded image?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

[image]I have generated a plotly table  and tried to export the embedded table. But it only export part of the table. So can anyone tell me how to show the whole table in a jupyter cell and export it correctly?  Thanks

The way i tried to export the table is :

```
import os

if not os.path.exists("imagesplotly"):
    os.mkdir("imagesplotly")

fig.write_image("imagesplotly/fig2.pdf")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust your pdf table by setting `height` in `fig.write_image` like this `fig.write_image("C://imagesplotly//fig1.pdf", height=yourDesiredHeight)`.

**Code 1 - The figure:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
lst1=np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=10).tolist()
lst2=np.random.uniform(low=0, high=100, size=10).tolist()

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(cells=dict(values=[np.random.rand(100,1), np.random.rand(100,1)]))])
fig.show()
```

**Jupyter output:**

[image]

I thought it would be a good idea to multiply the default number of pixels for a plotly table row by the length of your data, but I couldn't figure out the defaults. It sure isn't `255`, but the settings in the snippet below will capture the entire table for a list of length 100.

**Code 2 - The pdf output:**

```
pix = 225
datasize = len(lst1)

fig.write_image("C://imagesplotly//fig1.pdf", height=pix*datasize)
```

**pdf output (abbreviated):**

[image]